# CSS Background Clip IE support or disable

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Using background-clip on text works on everything but IE!

```
.main-menu .nav li a {
    font-family: freight-big-pro, serif;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #0f0e0e;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#cfac7e), color-stop(50%, #cfac7e), color-stop(50%, #0f0e0e));
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #cfac7e, #cfac7e 50%, #0f0e0e 50%);
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
}
```

On IE11 it just coming up as a black box with unreadable text, animation itself works but it's not clipping.

Now as background-clip isn't supported on text on IE, is there a way of Disabling this on just IE?

Comment: @SMAKSS IE11 only supports `background-clip: content-box;`, but not `background-clip: text;`.

Comment: @dai It's really something my client doesn't really need on his website... it just looks good! haha, but we'll see if anyone can come up with a solution... I've been trying to find one for about an hour now... no luck so far!

Comment: why is your client so adamant that you support IE11?

Comment: He is not. I am if anything. But is it worth supporting IE11? I just feel like I'm slacking as a web designer if I leave it looking broken on IE! @Dai

Comment: My own company stopped supporting IE11 last year. Global IE11 usage is now under 1.5% - even below 1% in most countries. You don't need to support it, really!

Comment: @Dai Thanks for this, put my mind to rest!

Answer (score 0):

You said, **On IE11 it just coming up as a black box with unreadable text, animation itself works but it's not clipping.**

I suggest try to use **-webkit-background-clip: text Polyfill** may help to fix this issue for IE 11 browser and it will also display properly in IE and other browsers.

Example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/TimPietrusky/background-clip-text-polyfill/master/background-clip-text-polyfill.js"></script>
<style>

body {
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  background:#fff;
  margin:0 1em;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
             url(http://timpietrusky.com/cdn/army.png) repeat;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

/*
 * This style will be shared with the SVG because
 * I have to replace the DOM element in Firefox. 
 * Otherwise the SVG pattern will be broken.
 */
.headline {
  font: bold 2.25em sans-serif;
}

svg {
  height: 8em;
  width: 100%;
}

/*
 * Just some styling... ignore it
 */
article {
  font-size:1.2em;
  border-top:.15em solid #7BB03B;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#5794C7;
  transition:color .15s ease-in-out;
  
  &:hover {
    color:#7BB03B;
  }
}
</style>
<script>
/**
  -webkit-background-clip: text Polyfill
  
  # What? #
  A polyfill which replaces the specified element with a SVG
  in browser where "-webkit-background-clip: text" 
  is not available.

  Fork it on GitHub
  https://github.com/TimPietrusky/background-clip-text-polyfill

  # 2013 by Tim Pietrusky
  # timpietrusky.com
**/

Element.prototype.backgroundClipPolyfill = function () {
  var a = arguments[0],
      d = document,
      b = d.body,
      el = this;

  function hasBackgroundClip() {
    return b.style.webkitBackgroundClip != undefined;
  };
  
  function addAttributes(el, attributes) {
    for (var key in attributes) {
      el.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
    }
  }
  
  function createSvgElement(tagname) {
    return d.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tagname);
  }
  
  function createSVG() {
    var a = arguments[0],
        svg = createSvgElement('svg'),
        pattern = createSvgElement('pattern'),
        image = createSvgElement('image'),
        text = createSvgElement('text');
    
    // Add attributes to elements
    addAttributes(pattern, {
      'id' : a.id,
      'patternUnits' : 'userSpaceOnUse',
      'width' : a.width,
      'height' : a.height
    });
    
    addAttributes(image, {
      'width' : a.width,
      'height' : a.height
    });
    image.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', a.url);
    
    addAttributes(text, {
      'x' : 0,
      'y' : 80,
      'class' : a['class'],
      'style' : 'fill:url(#' + a.id + ');'
    });
    
    // Set text
    text.textContent = a.text;
      
    // Add elements to pattern
    pattern.appendChild(image);
      
    // Add elements to SVG
    svg.appendChild(pattern);
    svg.appendChild(text);
    
    return svg;
  };
  
  /*
   * Replace the element if background-clip
   * is not available.
   */
  if (!hasBackgroundClip()) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      var svg = createSVG({
        'id' : a.patternID,
        'url' : a.patternURL,
        'class' : a['class'],
        'width' : this.width,
        'height' : this.height,
        'text' : el.textContent
      });
      
      el.parentNode.replaceChild(svg, el);
    }
    img.src = a.patternURL;
  }
};

var element = document.querySelector('.headline'); 

/*
 * Call the polyfill
 *
 * patternID : the unique ID of the SVG pattern
 * patternURL : the URL to the background-image
 * class : the css-class applied to the SVG
 */
element.backgroundClipPolyfill({
  'patternID' : 'mypattern',
  'patternURL' : 'http://timpietrusky.com/cdn/army.png',
  'class' : 'headline'
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="headline">-webkit-background-clip: text | Polyfill</h1>

<article>
  <h1>This is my sample text...</h1>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Reference:

[-webkit-background-clip: text polyfill](https://github.com/TimPietrusky/background-clip-text-polyfill)